# Продлить акцию на неделю, программно PHP

Tags: php, javascript, дата, datetime

Подскажите как сделать на php, продление акции на неделю программно. есть код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как в php сделать переменную поставить ее вместо текста в html, но чтобы она продлевалась каждый раз на неделю. До следующего понедельника.

Comment: В JS  можно использовать `Date.now()`, а в PHP использовать `date('d F')`. По поводу продления на неделю - тут нужна проверка, то есть условие (взять значение, к нему прибавить неделю и сравнить с текущей датой, если получилось больше чем текущая - продлить, если нет - не продлевать). Т.к. полного кода я не вижу - поэтому только общие советы в виде комментария. Полезные ссылки: [JS next Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078406/getting-the-date-of-next-monday) и [PHP next Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188728/get-the-date-of-next-monday-tuesday-etc)

Comment: @DenisBubnov полного кода и нет, в коде я не знаю как реализовать, числа смещаются поэтому просто прибавлять семь дней я не могу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$month = array("Января""Февраля","Марта","Апреля","Мая","Июня","Июля","Августа","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь");

$d = date('w');

if($d = 1) {
    $d = date('d', date(strtotime("+7 days")));
}

echo "Акция до " . $d ." " . $month[abs(date('m')) - 1];
```

Comment: спасибо, работает но выводит 20 число, хотя следующий понедельник это 19 февраля. И еще как вывести название месяца, февраля. Пробовал $d = date('m'); - выводит 02.

Comment: @stack-it  дополнил ответ.

Comment: Korushkin Подскажите , а возможно такое реализовать, чтобы выводил не 05 число, а 5, в остальном работает как надо.